# How do I report and interpret the output from linear mixed models with interaction terms?

Tags: mixed-model, interpretation, experiment-design, group-differences, lme4-nlme

So, we are doing a linear mixed effects model for analyzing some results of our study. In short, we have performed two different meal tests (i.e., two groups), and measured the response in various biomarkers at baseline as well as 1, 2, 3, and 4 hours after the meal.

I had a meeting with a statistician who explained that we should use linear mixed models for this and as such, using the `nlme` package in R the syntax looks like this:

```r
model <-lme(biomarker~ as.factor(group)*visit, random = ~1|ID, data=data, method="ML")
summary(model)
```

The output (abbreviated for readability):

```r
Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
 Data: data 
      AIC      BIC    logLik
  137.593 149.0651 -62.79649

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | ID
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:    1.462879 0.6039689

Fixed effects: biomarker ~ as.factor(group) * visit 
                            Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)              7.869766 0.7157143 38 10.995681  0.0000
as.factor(group)3        1.295118 1.0121729  8  1.279542  0.2366
visit                   -0.096024 0.0679003 38 -1.414191  0.1654
as.factor(group)3:visit -0.358905 0.0960255 38 -3.737606  0.0006
 Correlation: 
                        (Intr) as.()3 visit 
as.factor(group)3       -0.707              
visit                   -0.247  0.174       
as.factor(group)3:visit  0.174 -0.247 -0.707

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-3.107751422 -0.303320567  0.004573801  0.377750437  1.967646127 

Number of Observations: 50
Number of Groups: 10
```

To summarize:

- Exposure = one of two meal tests (group in the syntax)
- Outcome = Biomarker
- Time variable = Visit (5 in total for each participant, continuous)

My questions are:

1. Am I correct in interpreting this that there is an interaction between group and visit?
2. I am unclear as to how I should interpret the estimates here. Am I correct in saying that at time = 0, then the group difference (3 vs. 2) is 1.29? And further that this effect depends on the visit? What about the other timepoints?
3. Is it sufficient to report this model or should we also include a model without the interaction term that is just including group and visit?

Comment: You need to repeat this without `as.factor(group)3` in the model. It's contribution is not significant to the model: $p=0.2366$ is not significant. You may have to eliminate `visit` as well, but first check what the model shows without `as.factor(group)3`.

Comment: @Carl can you elaborate on why would one need to refit the model without non-significant predictors? That is not what I would do.

Comment: So alot of the comments have been deleted here, which is why my comments now seem very random. 

@Carl; I did not see your comment until now, I'm sorry. My questions is how to report and interpret the interaction when the simple (or main) effects are non-significant. And how to eventually report the model. In order to test the interaction, doesn't we need to add the individual covariates as well?

Comment: No, you should not remove `as.factor(group)3`. It is part of an interaction.  And you shouldn't remove variables just based on significance, either.

Comment: It seems that you are interested in checking effect of meal on  say,  Y.  and you have two types of meal- one for a  particular group and another for second group. The experiment makes measurements over time for each subject alongwith a baseline measurement i.e. prior to meal. Your questions can be answered if you give more details - number of subjects in each group. I recall that you had reported that there are 5 subjects for  each group  and 5 measurements for each subject.  To me , lme is not a solution. Probably u are interested in main effects and  ... please state problem explicitly.

Comment: @PeterFlom Perhaps. I suppose it does not matter that much that a model is over-determined if it is used for interpolation rather than to establish a physical model that also can serve as one for extrapolation. To do the latter, one has to wonder if the model used has any chance of being physical if the parameters are over-defined, or perhaps the question should be if there is not some other model without the inefficiency seen.

Comment: @Carl The possible overdetermination (we can't really tell if it's overdetrmined without more information) is a separate issue, but an important one.  But if you have a large interaction, then you need both main effects.  I am not sure why one variable is using 38 df.

Comment: It would help to know what baseline and effect models are doing. However, in general, I would model this as a nonlinear pharmacokinetic or pharmacodynamic times series at 0,1,2,3 and 4 hours with a dummy variable for meal type. The regression type I would use would depend on the exact characteristics of the modelling equation and type of noise. The data transformation type might include none, semi log, linear log, square root, the regressions might include ANOVA, weighted least squares, and Tikhonov regularization adaptive for the pharmacokinetic parameter of interest.

Comment: Even if I have understood your question properly, without the data, I cannot make a recommendation of less than chapter length. However, for such models, I can state that most current methods are of poor quality, and very few of them have less than the 5% error that I would consider more desirable to commit an act of science, and at least postulate a model that is not physically absurd.

Comment: @subhashc.davar I removed my comments because you removed your and mine suddenly seemed out of context. But yes, 5 participants per group for which we have 5 measurements of the outcome variable. What is the alternative to lme except repeated measures anova?

Comment: @Carl, so you are suggesting that linear mixed models is the wrong approach? I am not a statistician, but I am familiar with some of the alternatives you present. However, I was under the impression that when you have repeated outcome measures LMM is the way to go.

Comment: This is a pilot study and part of a post-doc project (not mine).

Comment: All I am suggesting is that you appear to have a time series that is most commonly amenable to pharmacokinetic modelling of oral dosing, if I am understanding what you are saying correctly. Please confirm that you are measuring plasma concentration or effect monitoring and of what kinetic type, e.g., first order, competitive binding to an enzymatic site, effect kinetics etc. The details here are essential to any recommendation for modeling, and even with the details it is not simple. Physics, if disrespected, will yield garbage of the "not significant" type.

Comment: @Carl the intervention specifically is meals with and without some amino acids (methionine and cysteine). The outcome variables are the baseline and resulting plasma concentrations of those and 17 other amino acids (1-4h) after the test meals. We are not measuring kinetics.

Comment: @Tho The comments indicate that you are interested in finding out whether there is any significant effect of meals with two particular amino acids (additional). IF you confirm that this is the goal of your study, I shall let you know the appropriate technique for your experimental data. The experimental design with repeated measures is good for your study.

Comment: The  linear mixed effects model is not suitable if  the objective is what I perceived.

Comment: @subhashc.davar I agree with you (+1) on comment. My guess is the linear mixed effects model is being applied to data without model testing for the assumptions of a) linearity and  b) normality, that is pharmacokinetic oral dosing type and *ad* a) is a time series of non-linear type with *ad* b) some peculiar characteristics, e.g., neither it nor residuals from it have much chance of symmetry, never mind normality from an imposed and likely irrelevant linearity.

Comment: @Carl thanks for your +1. Model testing does not appear to be important here.  The  data has been generated by implementing the experimental  design i.e. test group and control group based on with and without certain amino acids. Perhaps linearity and normality issues do not arise here. The data analysis and estimation of descriptive or survey data may have interest in  the  vitues of the two assumptions.

Comment: @subhashc.davar Using a time series as if time offered stationarity for relative amino acid concentrations, e.g., without cross-over, is probably not reasonable. Assumptions need testing, and that takes more thinking than applying a canned program.

Comment: @Carl I may be misinterpreting the idea of stationarity with regard to cocentrations of Amino acids, the data is one ..two .. four hours after meal. The data  further is of pooled nature: time series - cross section. As I interpret the effect of cross- over ( is it something like non- linear moment ?)  is neutralised when we have a number of subjects and series of measurements.  Hopefully, you will condone my poor understanding of medical science. I am a Commerce and management graduate.

Comment: @subhashc.davar Two kinds of people; those who know they are stupid, and those who do not. The former are scientists, and the latter, Democrats ($\leftarrow$ A joke, so laugh). Adding 2 amino acids to a meal might cause a cascade of  temporal disequilibrium; altered time constants for the amino acid pool. If one does not model the amino acids as changing non-linearly and differently for the two meals, the experimental effects may be missed. Conversely, if one has a model with both indispensable and not significant effects, one can ask why one feels stupid, or not.

Comment: @Carl The objective of experiment is to capture the overall effect of two amino-acids  and we have a test group and a control group.

Comment: @subhashc.davar Yes, and there appear to be 5 time-samples as well. All I am suggesting is that the time-samples may be very useful, but only if they are modeled tolerably well. Perhaps take a look at [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s40658-016-0166-z) to get some ideas. In that modelling paper the errors are circa 1%, and please note that the data have non-zero modes, just like postprandial data. Now imagine that the OP's postprandial data may have some amino acids with modes occurring at different times than for other amino acids, which if unmodelled may be problematic.

Comment: Time samples are not a problem. Different approaches to statistical analysis are  available and choice of such methods depends on nature of data and data- generation methodology.  Basic modelling requires technical know- how in the field of study. Here, the concern is which statistical model suits for  valid results given a specific objective. thanks for raising important issues.

Comment: Hello guys, sorry for the late response. So where to begin; @Carl, yes linearity is a problem here, especially for the two amino acids (and their related metabolites) that we manipulated. We are however looking at how the meals affected all the other amino acids as well as lipid profile, vitamin profile, glucose tolerance etc for which the curves are somewhat linear. From your discussion, I guess a formal test of the assumptions of lme must be carried out. I will definitely take your points to the statistician involved.

Comment: @subhashc.davar, you percieve correctly. Two groups in which 1) gets a meal without two amino acids and 2) gets a meal with two amino acids. Outcome variables are the amino acids in question (of course) but also several other plasma markers of lipid and amino acid metabolism. The experiment is fairly simple. Give either of the two meals, and take blood samples up to four hours after the meals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Am I correct in interpreting this that there is an interaction
>   between group and visit?

Yes.

> 2) I am unclear as to how I should interpret the estimates here. Am I
>   correct in saying that at time = 0, then the group difference (3 vs.
>   2) is 1.29? And further that this effect depends on the visit? What
>   about the other timepoints?

Yes, that is the group difference at time = 0 and yes, it depends on time.  You can calculate the estimate at any combination of the variables by using the formula:

$7.87 + 1.30*(I(\text{group} = 3)) - 0.10*\text{visit} - 0.36*(I(\text{group} = 3))*\text{visit}$

> 3) Is it sufficient to report this model or should we also include a
>   model without the interaction term that is just including group and
>   visit?

That depends on what you are interested in, but when there is an interaction, the model with only main effects can be misleading.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. Regarding your last point, I regularly see studies reporting the p-values and/or coefficients for the entire model with the interaction term. However, does a model like this really test for the differences between groups and does it make sense to report those estimates/p-values in a model with an interaction term? Finally, a means around this would maybe be to do post-hoc tests for the outcomes where the interaction is significant.

Comment: There are differences between groups that differ over time.

Comment: After some reading, I think I understand. This has been the most relevant answer so far, and I'll mark it as such. Thank you very much, Peter.